# How to efficiently observe changes to a list in ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

Suppose there is a `myList: MutableList<Int>` data in my ViewModel, and I want the interface to automatically observe changes when I modify this myList.

The following codes can work:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _listState = MutableStateFlow(listOf<Int>())
    val listState: StateFlow<List<Int>> = _listState.asStateFlow()

    fun appendListState() {
        _listState.value = _listState.value + 1
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen(model: MyViewModel) {
    val listValue = model.listState.collectAsState().value
    Column {
        Text(
            text = "Hello ${listValue}!",
            modifier = modifier
        )
        Button(onClick = {
            model.appendListState()
        }) {
            Text(text = "Add element")
        }
    }
}
```

But I think this is too inefficient because inserting a value into this list will reconstruct another list. If there are many elements in it, the efficiency will be very low. Is there an efficient way to observe changes?